# Is there reference to Jesus or the main Biblical characters outside the Bible?

Tags: bible

I would like to know if there exists documentation of Jesus/Mark/John/etc, as well as Moses/Abraham/Isaac/etc, outside of the Bible?

I would also prefer not to have reference from fellow Christian website, but purely u

Comment: Indeed, but this is not only for Jesus though... But thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). It looks as though you did not finish writing your question. You can edit it to complete the sentence, and whatever else you might want to add. For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Comment: Do you consider non-canonical Jewish and Christian writings to be acceptable sources?

Answer (score 1):

*The Popular Handbook of Archaeology and the Bible,* by Joseph M. Holden and Norman Geisler, pp303-305 gives a list of many names  of "New Testament Persons Cited in Ancient Non-Christian Sources."

Some of those names include:

Herod Agrippa I and II, Ananias (high priest), Annas (high priest), Herod Antipas, Herod Archelaus, Caesare Augusus (Octavious), Bernice,
Aciaphas (high priest), Emporer Claudius, Drusilla, Felix, Porcius Festus, Gallio, Gamaliel, King Herod (Judea), Herodias, James (sone of Mary), Jesus (of Nazareth), John the Baptist, Joseph (adoptive father of Jesus), Judas the Galilean, Pontius Pilate, Quirinius, Salome, Sergius Paulus, Theudas, Tiberias Caesar.

The pages give the source of the mentions as well as the verses they appear in the Bible.